# Build a chrome push notification extension that allows the user to choose different sections of a webpage to get notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, desktop

I am working on a chrome extension to give desktop push notifications to the users from my eCommerce website that has different product categories. I would like the users to receive notifications only when there are updates in the categories they are interested in i.e phones category, furniture, home appliance

Example A: User is interested in phones, therefore I would want them to receive notifications from the phones category only

Users should select their category of choice from popup.html after clicking the extension icon. 
I have the extension almost ready in that, it's displaying desktop notifications but only from one link(category). How can I get the extension to include the other categories?

Answer (score 0):

If a user select their category of choice from popup.html, then you may send the choice to your website using JSON data by ajax,
after that you server will take the user's categories of choice and save it in database table that responsible to user's categories of choice.

So when there are updates in some products from different categories at your eCommerce website ,
then you just save the relevant notifications in relevant table (let's call it for this example: user's notification),
because when your chrome extension ( assuming that it will try to request data from your server all the time by the time you configure) 
request new data then your web server will return the relevant data from user's notification table, and that's how every user will get relevant data.

Let me know if this helped you or not, so I will try to add other information or edit my current answer,
Thanks

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, I have the extension showing notifications from all categories. I don't know if this makes it simpler since I now have separate functions for different categories. Can I now call different functions to run after a user selects and option?

Comment: Notice if you don't have DB table that handle the user's notification then what data you return to the client side? do you return all of the notifications?

Comment: So if you want to return all the notification from the server (this will return some data that not relevant to the user) you need to build a JavaScript function that choose the user’s relevant data to be shown and this can be done if you return notification combined with string that indicate the type of it.